# Refreshing page for ASP.NET MVC page without hitting the controller twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing tabs on a page which should repopulate a dropdown list which is located at a parent level within the layout. I am using the concept of model builders and have written extension methods. Currently I have some jquery which when pressing the tab does an ajax request to the controller method which returns the correct view based on the ViewModel which is being passed in.

But i want to refresh the page on a ajax request whilst retaining the selection of the tabs but it does not want to play. If i do a location.reload() function it will go to the controller method, once by the ajax and then the second on the reload.

Not sure how i can resolve this but my code is below:

```
public ViewResult SalesCustomerOutcome(Args args, string type)
        {
            args.SelectedTab = type;

            return View<SalesCustomerOutcomeBuilder>(args);
        }
```

The builder will build up the relevant options such as the dropdown menu but i do require a page refresh.

My builder does the following:

```
      args.AvailableViews = null;

        if (args.SelectedTab == null)
        {
            args.SelectedTab = "advice";
        }

        switch (args.SelectedTab)
        {
            case "brandProduct":
                args.AvailableViews = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "By Product", Value = "Product" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "By Brand", Value = "Brand" }
                };
                break;                    
            case "skill" :
                args.AvailableViews = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Applications", Value = "Applications" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Advances", Value = "Advances" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Review", Value = "Review" }
                };
                break;
            case "advice":
                args.AvailableViews = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Advised", Value = "Advice" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Non Advised", Value = "NonAdvice" }
                };
                break;       
            default:
                args.AvailableViews = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "By Product", Value = "Product" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "By Brand", Value = "Brand" }
                };
                break;
        }


        //Select the first viewtype of current list.
        if (args.ViewType == null) args.ViewType = args.AvailableViews.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();

        var inputGrid = InputGridBuilder.Build(args);
        var feedback = FeedbackBuilder.Build(inputGrid.Report.Id);

        if (args.ViewType == "Brand")
        {
            return new SalesCustomerBrandOutcomeVM
            {
                FeedbackModel = feedback,
                InputGrid = inputGrid,
                Items = call to stored proc
            };
        }
        else if (args.ViewType == "Product")
        {
            return (ReportVM)new SalesCustomerProductOutcomeVM
            {
                FeedbackModel = feedback,
                InputGrid = inputGrid,
                Items = args.ViewType == "Product" ? Data.GetSalesCustomerProductOutcomeMMR(inputGrid.Employee.ID, inputGrid.DatePeriod).ToList() : Data.GetSalesCustomerBrandProductOutcomeMMR(inputGrid.Employee.ID, inputGrid.DatePeriod, args.ViewType).ToList()
            };       
        }
        else if(args.ViewType == "Skills")
        {
            return (ReportVM)new SalesCustomerSkillOutcomeVM
            {
                FeedbackModel = feedback,
                InputGrid = inputGrid,
                Items = //some stuff here which i cannot show
            };       
        }
        else 
        {
            return (ReportVM) new SalesCustomerAdviceOutcomeVM
            {
                FeedbackModel = feedback,
                InputGrid = inputGrid,
                Items = //call to stored proc
            };
        }
```

The available views is the dropdown list which gets built up.

jquery:

```
function tabItemClicked(a, action) {
var container = $(a).parents('div.tabs');
var resultDiv = $($(a).attr('href'), container);
alert($(a).attr('href'));
//check if a tab has been selected. This helps when page has been refreshed.
var selectedTab = $("#salesTabs").tabs("option", "selected");
var type = null;
if (selectedTab == 0) {
type = "brandProduct";
}
else if (selectedTab == 1) {
type = "advice"
}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: action,
cache: false,
data: { type: type },
success: function (html) {
//location.reload();
/*resultDiv.html = ('');
resultDiv.html(html);*/
}
});
```

So after the ajax request i need to refresh the menu but is this possible?

Comment: Its not clear why you want to refresh the page and maintain the same tab. To do this however, you have to have a specific action which will load the correct tab. And when you are serving that page you'd have to work though that action only. So this is how I am suggesting your controller/action should be written.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid hitting the controller twice?

Comment: As it's not good to have two postbacks that's why. The dropdown is at the parent level that needs to be refreshed with different settings